# Bullet Physics on Smartphone? (Android / iPhone)

Tags: game-engine, gamekit, smartphone, game-physics, bulletphysics

Is this possible on a Smartphone (Android / iPhone)? I think is called Bullet Physic.

I mean realtime in the app. The user sets the ball, and then explosion / destruction.

Must not be so perfect. Simple color. Only the physics are important.

Only the explosion / destruction is important to me.

[Video 1](http://youtu.be/pGn3kNCPpHk)

[Video 2](http://youtu.be/OPUAtihkiwM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I develop app for iOS and Android (using Marmalade) with bullet physics.
Bullet physics has no "destruction"

You must put all parts together and make them sleep

```
body->forceActivationState(ISLAND_SLEEPING);
```

Then you shoot with a ball and you get such a picture.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can use it on iphone http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2011/11/18/creating-a-physics-based-opengl-ios-app/

I myself am trying to find out how to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. Here's a nice article explaining how to set BulletPhysics for iOS development: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1914612

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Bullet in my Android project. The setup was relatively simple when following this page:
http://jackietutorial.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-port-bullet-for-android.html

If this link goes invalid, you can always search the net for "bullet4droid" which is essentially the result of the steps in that article.

As for getting Fracturing to work on Android/iOS, I don't see why not, though you will probably need to limit the amount of shards based on the processing power of the device.

You can download Bullet here:
https://code.google.com/p/bullet/

There is a VoronoiFractureDemo.cpp file that comes with the engine which I have not tried, but in theory it should do the same thing on any device. You just need to call your own drawing functions.

Note that the tutorial mentioned above was designed for the later 2.X releases. It looks like 3.X is designed primarily with OpenCL/hardware acceleration in mind, so I would guess that it would be unsupported for now due to the lack of support for OpenCL on Android/iOS.

Answer (score 0):

use **Jbullet** ( java port of bullet ) for android
[download jbullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/)